# Circular Limited Sums

Tags: code-golf, restricted-complexity

## Challenge

Let's imagine an `N`-tuple of integers between 0 and `M` inclusive, and let's call it `F`.

There are `(M + 1) ** N` possible `F`s in total.

How many such `F`s satisfy all of the following inequalities (index is one-based)?

- `F[n] + F[n+1] <= M` for `1 <= n < N`
- `F[N] + F[1] <= M`

Write a program or function that takes two **positive integers** `N` and `M` and outputs the answer in any convenient form.

### Test Cases

```
(N,M) => Answer

(1,1) => 1
(2,1) => 3
(3,1) => 4
(4,1) => 7

(1,2) => 2
(2,2) => 6
(3,2) => 11
(4,2) => 26

(10,3) => 39175
(10,4) => 286555
(10,5) => 1508401

(25,3) => 303734663372
(25,4) => 43953707972058
(25,5) => 2794276977562073

(100,3) => 8510938110502117856062697655362747468175263710
(100,4) => 3732347514675901732382391725971022481763004479674972370
(100,5) => 60964611448369808046336702581873778457326750953325742021695001
```

### Explanation

```
M (max value of element) = 1

F[1] + F[1] <= 1; F = [0]
(1,1) => 1

F[1] + F[2] <= 1; F = [0,0], [0,1], [1,0]
(2,1) => 3

F = [0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,1,0], [1,0,0]
(3,1) => 4

F = [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,1], [0,0,1,0], [0,1,0,0], [0,1,0,1], [1,0,0,0], [1,0,1,0]
(4,1) => 7

---

M = 2

F[1] + F[1] <= 2; F = [0], [1]
(1,2) => 2

F = [0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [1,0], [1,1], [2,0]
(2,2) => 6

F = [0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,0,2], [0,1,0], [0,1,1], [0,2,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,1],
[1,1,0], [1,1,1], [2,0,0]
(3,2) => 11

(4,2) => 26 (left as exercise for you)
```

## Rules

- This is a [restricted-complexity](/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity) challenge. **The time complexity of your code should be polynomial in `M` and `N`** (e.g. you can't generate all `(M + 1) ** N` tuples and then check for the condition). Please explain your approach in your submission.
- Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest answer in bytes wins.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/) with [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), 59 bytes

```python
lambda M,N:trace(mat(tri(M+1)[::-1])**N)
from numpy import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY27DgIhEAB7vmJLQCzWkuQ@AYprT4tVDyWRRzZrcV@PZ4zlTCaZvsmz1dNI03m8qFzvBMFFL0y3VRcSLZx1OKBZvD/ixVgbjUrcCtR36Rvk0huLHfPEVB@rRoe4B40hQK4wewVfiH@AzrkKRBdc0vvJqJ8ZHw)

Uses matrix multiplication to count paths. If float precision is an issue, the `mat` could specify `mat(...,int)`.

Comment: Using `mat(...,int)` does not seem to work for the `n=100` cases. The method is correct (using sympy to sum the powers of the roots of the characteristic polynomial does work, for example), but numpy goes wrong somewhere as the numbers increase (maybe it's the `**` power operator?)

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 27 bytes

```
.N?Ys:RTtYh-QNgQ+NTs:Rdtszh
```

[Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.N%3FYs%3ARTtYh-QNgQ%2BNTs%3ARdtszh&input=5%0A100&debug=1)

Expects input in the format:

```
M
N
```

This is classic dynamic programming, over the left end of the values set so far, the right end, and the current size of the gap.

How it works, in pseudocode/Python:

```
.N          | define memoized fill(left, right, gap):
?           | if cap > 0 then
s:RTtY      | sum(fill(i, right, gap - 1)
h-QN        |     for i in range(M - left + 1))
gQ+NT       | else M >= left + right
            | output:
s:Rdtsz     | sum(fill(i, i, N - 1)
h           |     for i in range(M + 1))
```

`Q` is used for `M`, `z` is used for `N`, `:` is `fill`, `N` is `left`, `T` is `right`, `Y` is `gap`.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
Q:&>~PiY^Xds
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P9BKza4uIDMyLiKl@P9/Uy5DAwA) This is a direct translation of [xnor's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164370/56433) and my first MATL answer, so it's most likely not optimal. E.g. there is likely a shorter way to get an upper-left triangular matrix of ones than `t&lYRP`. *Edit: And it turns out there is, namely `:&>~P`. Thanks to Luis Mendo for -1 byte!*

```
               M is the first input and N the second
Q:             increment M and generate range from 1 to M+1
  &>           compare vector element wise with itself with greater-than function
               results in a upper-right triangular matrix
    ~          inverse to get lower-left triangular matrix
     P         flip rows to get upper-left triangular matrix
      i        input N
       Y^      take the matrix to the power of N
         Xds   compute the sum of the main diagonal
```

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks! Though it's only one byte or is there something else which can be dropped?

Comment: No, that's it, I can't count :-D

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
°(√&╒íÆ½╨⌂'├╖▼1_Z
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=f828fb26d5a192abd07f27c3b71f315f5a&i=1+1%0A2+1%0A3+1%0A4+1%0A1+2%0A2+2%0A3+2%0A4+2%0A10+3%0A10+4%0A10+5%0A25+3%0A25+4%0A25+5%0A100+3%0A100+4%0A100+5%0A&a=1&m=2)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
^1](    [1, 0, ... 0] with M zeroes
:)      get all rotations of the array
{       begin block
  {:+rm map each array to reverse(prefixSums(arr))
},v*    execute preceding block N-1 times
F       for each array, execute the rest of the program
  iT    remove the last i elements from the array, where i is the iteration index
  F+    add the remaining elements to the running total
        implicitly print output
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%5E1]%28+++%09[1,+0,+...+0]+with+M+zeroes%0A%3A%29+++++%09get+all+rotations+of+the+array%0A%7B++++++%09begin+block%0A++%7B%3A%2Brm%09map+each+array+to+reverse%28prefixSums%28arr%29%29%0A%7D,v*+++%09execute+preceding+block+N-1+times%0AF++++++%09for+each+array,+execute+the+rest+of+the+program%0A++iT+++%09remove+the+last+i+elements+from+the+array,+where+i+is+the+iteration+index%0A++F%2B+++%09add+the+remaining+elements+to+the+running+total%0A+++++++%09implicitly+print+output&i=1+1%0A2+1%0A3+1%0A4+1%0A1+2%0A2+2%0A3+2%0A4+2%0A10+3%0A10+4%0A10+5%0A25+3%0A25+4%0A25+5%0A100+3%0A100+4%0A100+5%0A&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 72 bytes

```r
function(M,N)sum(diag(Reduce(`%*%`,rep(list(outer(0:M,0:M,"+")<=M),N))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T8NXx0@zuDRXIyUzMV0jKDWlNDlVI0FVSzVBpyi1QCMns7hEI7@0JLVIw8DKVweElbSVNG1sfTWB@oDgf5qGqY6hgeZ/AA)

Ports xnor's approach.

Fails for larger test cases as R only has 32-bit integer support (they get cast to `double` once the max int value is reached), so using `gmp` or another arbitrary precision arithmetic library would be required.

Strangely, R lacks a matrix power operator, as `^` always applies elementwise.

Comment: Actually, there is a properly implemented `%^%` operator in package `expm` that would allow for [-5 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T8NXx0@zuDRXIyUzMV1DI7@0JLVIw8DKVweElbSVNG1sfTVV41T9NDW5cjKTihKLKjWUUisKcpU0/6dpmOoYGmj@BwA), but unfortunately, it is not available on TIO (I had to test locally).

Comment: @KirillL. yeah, I had considered that but I think I'll stick with my base R response. Also you can golf that down to 60 bytes by not loading in the whole package: `function(M,N)sum(diag(expm::\`%^%\`(outer(0:M,0:M,"+")<=M,N)))`

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <sup><s>31</s></sup> 25 bytes

```apl
+/1 1⍉+.×⍣(⎕-1)⍨⌽∘.≤⍨⍳1+⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG9qQMCjtglGBlyPOtrT/mvrGyoYPurt1NY7PP1R72INoLyuoeaj3hWPevY@6pih96hzCYjTu9lQGyj1H6jnfxqXKZehAQA)

A full program which takes N, then M as inputs.

Follows the same algorithm as xnor's Python solution.

-6 bytes from Bubbler.

Comment: `{x+.×⍵}⍣(...) → x+.×⍣(...)`, then `x+.×⍣(...)⊢x←... → +.×⍣(...)⍨` to get [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG9qQMCjtglGBlyPOtrT/mvrGyoYPurt1NY7PP1R72INoLyuoeaj3hWPevY@6pih96hzCYjTu9lQGyj1H6jnfxqXKZehAQA).

Comment: Should've spotted that. Thanks!